# Как спрятать автокомплит

Tags: angular

Шаблон родительского компонента

```
<input#autocomp>
<app-autocomplete
  [autocompleteField]=autocomp>
</app-autocomplete>
```

шаблон дочернего компонента

```
<ul *ngIf="isShow">
  <li *ngFor="let item of data" (click)="getItem(item)">
    {{ item.label }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

дочерний компонент

```
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() autocompleteField: HTMLInputElement;
  @Input() data: DataAuto[];
  @Output() onItemSelected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  public isShow: boolean;

  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() {
    const input = this.autocompleteField;
    const inputFocus$ = fromEvent(input, 'focus');
    const inputBlur$ = fromEvent(input, 'blur');

    inputFocus$.pipe(
      tap(_ => this.isShow = true)
    ).subscribe()

    inputBlur$.pipe(

    ).subscribe()

  }

  getItem(item: DataAuto) {
    this.onItemSelected.emit(item.payload);
  }
}
```

Подскажите как сделать, когда происходит событие blur список прятался, но если клик происходит по списку, то значение item.label подставлялось в инпут и только потом список прятался?

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: код, который ты вставил невоспроизводимый, я не могу по картинке определить какую задачу ты решаешь, используй stackblitz или codesandbox

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcfglh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fautocomplete%2Fautocomplete.component.ts

Comment: такс, я вижу инпут просто, а что нужно сделать? :)

Comment: при вводе в инпут своего логин guthub появится т.к. называемый автокомплит), как сделать чтобы при клике на вариант автокомплита, выбиралось значение и потом автокомплит скрывался, а при клике в не автокомплита, автокомплит просто прятался

Comment: [есть такое пример директивы click outside](https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/angular-2-a-simple-click-outside-directive/), вешаешь ее на `ul` и слушаешь событие, когда событие диспатчится - скрываешь список. `li` добавляешь `(click)` и скрываешь при клике)

Comment: спасибо, попробую